# Accessing Checkboxes Values And Using Functions in PHP

Tags: php, function, checkbox

I am having problem in this situation, i searched alot and don't know what should i do with it....
I have got like 4 checkboxes, on each checkbox a certain function is being performed. I have this html code for checkboxes,

```
    <form action="check.php" method="post">
<table border="1" width="200">
<tr>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" name="first[]" value="option1" />
</td>
<td width="500">
<strong>Option 1</strong>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" name="first[]" value="option2" />
</td>
<td width="500">
<strong>Option 2</strong>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" name="first[]" value="option3" />
</td>
<td width="500">
<strong>option 3</strong>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table border="1" width="200">
<tr>
<td>
<input type="text" name="entered_value"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table border="1" width="200">
<tr>
<td>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

I am accessing these checkboxes using this code

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        if(isset($_POST['first']))
            {
                $get_data_checkboxes = $_POST['first'];
            }   
        else
            {
                $get_data_checkboxes = "";
            }
            print_r($get_data_checkboxes);
            exit();
}
?>
```

What i am facing problem is like i need to run a function on each checkbox ticked, e.g. if the person ticks Option 1 then i should be able to run function 1 and so on...

any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select multiple checkboxes, you can try something like this:

```
for( $i = 0; $i < count( $_POST['first'] ); $i++ ) {

    if( $_POST['first'][$i] == 'option1' ) {

        echo "function1";

    } else if( $_POST['first'][$i] == 'option2' ) {

        echo "function2";

    } else if( $_POST['first'][$i] == 'option3' ) {

        echo "function3";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the line

```
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
```

Without that your code works fine, and you can use that to call your functions like this:

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['first']))
    {
         $get_data_checkboxes = $_POST['first'];
         foreach($get_data_checkboxes as $value){
             //call functions named option1(), option2(), etc..
             call_user_func($value);
         }
    }   
    else{
        $get_data_checkboxes = "";
    }

?>
```